# Is Epson Perfection 4990 Photo scanner Windows 10 compatible?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, compatibility, scanner

When upgraded to Windows 10 on the Epson site Windows 10 wasn't mentioned for the Perfection 4990 Photo scanner compatibility, but the scanner driver + scan utility worked fine.

Now since a couple of days when I start the scan utility I get the following message:

[image]

I noticed that this was after a Windows update, though I don't know if the two are related.

I already tried re-installing both driver and scan utility from the Epson website, and restarting my PC. I hadn't changed my USB port, but changing it doesn't solve the problem, nor does any other suggestion from the Troubleshooting Assistant.

Did the Windows update break the compatibility? Is there a way to get the scanner to work again?

Answer (score 1):

While the device previously worked on a USB3 port, it no longer did. Like I said in OP, also moving it to another port didn't solve the problem.

The solution was to move it to a legacy *USB2* port.